# Saving list view items when switching between fragments

Tags: android

I'm building a chat application. I have a ChannelFragment containing a list view of channels that I can populate by pressing a button. When I click on an item, I move to another fragment called MessageFragment which contains chats from that channel. However, when I navigate to the ChannelFragment using the nav bar, the whole list view is refreshed and nothing is there.

How can I save the created items in the list view after switching to the message fragment? Thank you.

**The list view in my ChannelFragment**

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    channelList = new ArrayList<>();

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        nick = bundle.getString("nick");
        channel = bundle.getString("channel");
    }

    channelList.add(new Channel(channel, "0 people"));

    channelListView = getView().findViewById(R.id.channelListView);
    adapter = new ChannelListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.adapter_view_channel_layout, channelList);
    channelListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    channelListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            Channel item = adapter.getItem(position);
            Bundle messageBundle = new Bundle();
            messageBundle.putString("nick",nick);
            messageBundle.putString("channel",item.getChannelName());
            MessageFragment messageFragment = new MessageFragment();
            messageFragment.setArguments(messageBundle);

            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.layout_for_fragments, messageFragment, "MessageF").commit();
        }
    });


}
```

**How I navigate to it**

```
  @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

    int id = menuItem.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.channels) {
        ChannelFragment channelFragment = new ChannelFragment();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.layout_for_fragments, channelFragment, "Channel Fragment");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

**The first pic is when I create the items and the second one is when I navigate back from the message fragment**
[image: When I create the list view]

[image: When I come back to it from the message fragment]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 parts to this answer

1) because you `channelList = new ArrayList<>();` in `onViewCreated` every time `onViewCreated` is called you are wiping the list. Don't create a new list at this point, create empty list when you define the variable as a member of the class e.g. where the define what type channelList variable is.

When you switch to a new fragment it is usual for the old fragment instance to be put to the backstack and then re-used when you go back to it.

That `new` in `onViewCreated` is wiping the list when you are returning from the backstack at the moment.

e.g. the code will be something like

```java
public class ChannelFragment extends Fragment {
  private ArrayList<Channel> channelList = new ArrayList<>();
....
```

2)
Make you `Channel` object Parcelable

A tutorial https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidParcelable/article.html

You can then use `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`

To use `writeParcelableList` or `writeTypedList` to store the list of channels if the Fragment gets destroyed

See https://www.dev2qa.com/android-fragment-save-retrieve-instance-state-example/

Comment: Thank you very much for you reply, I appreciate it! Not sure if I can manage the second part but I will try.

Comment: Depending on how you are navigating around your Fragments, a fragment being destroyed is not so common because it would only be done is low memory conditions.
BUT you would need to do Part 2 as part of handling screen rotation events where the fragments and parent Activity get destroyed and re-created