# Fragment refresh by attach() and detach() to reload data from db

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

In my android application I'm loading data from database into a ListView inside a Fragment. If the query returns empty from the database, a textview is displayed saying "Nothing to Display" but if there is data recieved, it shows "List of Items" and below it is a ListView with the data retrieved. Everything works but the problem is that when I launch the application with an Empty database it shows the textview "Nothing to Display" but when I insert data into the database while the app is running, go to another fragment and return back it shows "List of Items" with no items in the Listview below and I need to relaunch the app for the data to appear in the ListView.

I looked up for solutions and they said it could be fixed by refreshing/reloading the fragment by attaching and detaching the fragment.

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
            case R.id.js_nav_home:
                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.js_fragment_container, new js_HomeFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.js_nav_profile:
                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.js_fragment_container, profileFragment)
                        .commit();
                break;
            case R.id.js_nav_find:
                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.js_fragment_container, new js_MatchFragment())
                        .commit();
                break;
            case R.id.js_nav_logout:
                finish();
                break;
        }

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

I tried

```
manager.beginTransaction().detach().attach(this).
                        replace(R.id.js_fragment_container, new js_HomeFragment()).commit();
```

But I dont know what parameters to put in the "detach()" function. or If that's the correct way to detach and attach.

Thank you! Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: This sounds exactly like the problem in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59446471/2373819

Comment: I just want to refresh/reload my fragment by using detach and attach

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you are fetching the data in the Fragment´s onCreate method but the view is recreated always that you select your Fragment, calling the onCreateView method but never fetching another time the data... so you need to fetch them when the database is updated...

The fast solution is always to fetch the data in the onViewCreated method, but is not a good idea because if the data are not updated is not necessary to fetch them.

So the best solution depends on your architecture, for example, if you are using a shared ViewModel, you can update the LiveData when the data are saved and when the Fragment recreates the view, populate the last LiveData values.

Another way is to use a BroadcastReceiver but is not a good solution too...

Use the best way to your architecture and it is necessary to understand the Fragment ´s lifecycle and be careful with the LiveDatas because always are the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .detach(this)
                .attach(this)
                .commit();
```

Calls the `onCreateView` method again and redraws the view hierarchy.